# Node Stack Overflow Errors using R FAST package

Tags: r, stack-overflow

I am attempting to run a Fourier Amplitude Sensitivity Test (FAST) using the fast package for R. This package was removed from the CRAN archive "on 2020-08-29 as email to the maintainer bounced." I had not used this package before attempting now so I can't be sure this error would not have been present prior to 2020-8-29.

However, when trying to generate an array to use for FAST through the `fast_parameters` function, I run into errors:

```
> library (fast)
> fast_parameters(0,1,"test")
Error: node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

Version info:

```
$version.string
[1] "R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try installing older versions [from here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fast/)